# How to get colored emails from crontab?

Tags: python, colors, console, cron, ansi-escape

I call a Python script from crontab. The script does generates colored output using ANSI escapes but when crontab is sending the mail with the output I see the escapes instead of colors.

What is happening is logic but I would like to know if it would be possible to generate a html message instead.

I would like a solution that does not require to implement the email notification myself.

Comment: If you are looking for a solution without programming, then the question is not programming related, isn't it? 
I would suggest you trying on superuser.com

Comment: Is not about "without" programming - Is just about finding a simple and nice way to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try with some txt to html converter, for example, http://txt2html.sourceforge.net/, you can also use pygments with some modifications.